# pessoal eu não sei de onde vem o erro de sintaxe da linha " else " no final ,poderiam me ajudar

Tags: php

```
<?php
  require("conexaobancodedados_Model.php");
  $nomeEvento = $_POST['nome_evento'];
  $descricaoEvento = $_POST['descricao_evento'];
  $imagem = $_FILES['imagem']['tmp_name'];
  $tamanho = $_FILES['imagem']['size'];
  $tipo = $_FILES['imagem']['type'];
  $nome = $_FILES['imagem']['name'];

  if ( $imagem != "none" )
  {
      $fp = fopen($imagem, "rb");
      $conteudo = fread($fp, $tamanho);
      $conteudo = addslashes($conteudo);
      fclose($fp);

  $queryInsercao = "INSERT INTO tabela_imagens (nome_evento, descrição_evento, nome_imagem, tamanho_imagem, tipo_imagem, imagem) VALUES ('$nomeEvento', '$descricaoEvento','$nome','$tamanho', '$tipo','$conteudo')";

   mysql_query($queryInsercao) or die("Algo deu errado ao inserir o registro. Tente novamente.");
  echo 'Registro inserido com sucesso!'; 
  header('Location: index.php');
   if(mysql_affected_rows($conexao) > 0) {
       print "A imagem foi salva na base de dados.";
   }else{
       print "Não foi possível salvar a imagem na base de dados.";
   }
  else{
      print "Não foi possível carregar a imagem.";
    }
```

Comment: Qual erro? em qual linha? em qual `else`?

Comment: @hugo você deveria explicar melhor sua dúvida inserindo comentários em partes do código, veja como fazer [stack](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: Olá hugo, seja bem vindo ao SOpt! Como você é novato, sugiro ver [como fazer uma boa pergunta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) ou se ainda tiver dúvidas de como funciona o site, você pode fazer um pequeno [tour por aqui](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/tour).

Answer (score 2):

Tá faltando uma `}` pra fechar o primeiro `if`

```
<?php
require("conexaobancodedados_Model.php");
$nomeEvento = $_POST['nome_evento'];
$descricaoEvento = $_POST['descricao_evento'];
$imagem = $_FILES['imagem']['tmp_name'];
$tamanho = $_FILES['imagem']['size'];
$tipo = $_FILES['imagem']['type'];
$nome = $_FILES['imagem']['name'];

if ( $imagem != "none" )
{
    $fp = fopen($imagem, "rb");
    $conteudo = fread($fp, $tamanho);
    $conteudo = addslashes($conteudo);
    fclose($fp);

    $queryInsercao = "INSERT INTO tabela_imagens (nome_evento, descrição_evento, nome_imagem, tamanho_imagem, tipo_imagem, imagem) VALUES ('$nomeEvento', '$descricaoEvento','$nome','$tamanho', '$tipo','$conteudo')";

    mysql_query($queryInsercao) or die("Algo deu errado ao inserir o registro. Tente novamente.");
    echo 'Registro inserido com sucesso!'; 
    header('Location: index.php');
    if(mysql_affected_rows($conexao) > 0) {
        print "A imagem foi salva na base de dados.";
    }else{
        print "Não foi possível salvar a imagem na base de dados.";
    }
} // Falta esta chave
else {
    print "Não foi possível carregar a imagem.";
}
```

Comment: Posso editar e pôr o código inteiro?

Comment: Sim, sem problemas, estou no celular.... Muito ruim de mexer com o código aqui

Comment: Tranquilo, editei. Eu sei como é ruim mexer em respostas pelo celular.

Comment: Pois é... rs. Obrigado =]